# Loop through array of objects with access to index and objects and support continue, break, return

Tags: javascript

I am looking for loop through array of objects with access to index and object.

It also has to support continue, break, return.

```
objects = [{}, {}]

for(let [index, object] of objects)
```

or

```
for(let [index, object] in objects)
```

These things don't work for me.

Comment: Please show the complete code, to see exactly what don't work for you

Comment: You're looking for `entries`: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/entries

Comment: If you need to access the index of each object in the array as you act on it, you might be better off using `foreach`

Comment: Either `for(let [index, object] in objects.entries())` or `objects.forEach((object, index) =>{ // loop code here })`

Answer (score 0):

Why not just a regular for?

```
for(let index = 0; index < objects.length; i++) {
    const obj = objects[index];

    if (obj.something) {
        continue;
    }

    if (obj.somethingelse) {
        break;
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

A better way to loop through objects

1. Object.keys
2. Object.values
3. Object.entries(i think u want this)

**Object Key**

```js
const fruits = {
  apple: 28,
  orange: 17,
  pear: 54,
}

const keys = Object.keys(fruits)
console.log(keys) // [apple, orange, pear]

// Looping through arrays created from Object.keys

for (const key of keys) {
  console.log(key)
}

// Results:
// apple
// orange
// pear
```

**

```js
const fruits = {
  apple: 28,
  orange: 17,
  pear: 54,
}

const values = Object.values(fruits)
console.log(values) // [28, 17, 54]
```

**
**Object.entries**

```js
const fruits = {
  apple: 28,
  orange: 17,
  pear: 54,
}

const entries = Object.entries(fruits)
console.log(entries)
// [
//   [apple, 28],
//   [orange, 17],
//   [pear, 54]
// ]
for (const [fruit, count] of entries) {
  console.log(`There are ${count} ${fruit}s`)
}

// Result
// There are 28 apples
// There are 17 oranges
// There are 54 pears
```